# How to apply rotation for Text in blender?

Tags: transforms, parent, instances, transform-orientation, vertex-parent

**Target** : Trying to use instance for text in circle

Current without text rotation:

[image]

**After Rotation of text for X (Problem)**

[image]

Circle Instance Properties:

[image]

**Required: Align to Vertex Normal**

[image]

**Tried**:
Converted to Mesh and then applied rotation.
**Disadvantage**: It is tedious and cannot edit it later.

Comment: You could do this with Geometry Nodes. Would this be an option?